# Radiative corrections to $V-A$ and $V+A$ currents

Tags: standard-model, perturbation-theory, quarks

In Appendix A of the following reference, p.128,

Masaru Doi, Tsuneyuki Kotani, Eiichi Takasugi, Double Beta Decay and Majorana Neutrino, Progress of Theoretical Physics Supplement, Volume 83, March 1985, Pages 1–175, https://doi.org/10.1143/PTPS.83.1

The radiative correction to arbitrary order of perturbation to the effective tree level $V\pm A$ quark current is given as,
\begin{align}
\overline{u}\gamma^\mu(1\mp\gamma^5)d = \overline{u}(p_1)\Gamma^{\rho\nu ... ..\lambda}\gamma^\mu(1\mp\gamma^5)\Gamma'_{\rho\nu ... ..\lambda}d(p_2), \tag{1}\label{eqn1}
\end{align}
where $u$ and $d$ are up and down quarks. $\Gamma^{\rho\nu ... ..\lambda}$ consists of $\gamma^\mu$, $\gamma^\nu$, ...... $\gamma^\lambda$, $\gamma^\mu p_{1\mu}$, $\gamma^\mu p_{2\mu}$, masses of quarks and coupling constants. How do we get the r.h.s of \eqref{eqn1} from l.h.s by applying radiative correction?

Comment: You are misreading/conflating two formulas there, (A.2.19) with (A.2.20). The latter is every possible radiative correction to the former, your left hand side. It just preserves charge, color (0), and Lorentz invariance. Write down just *one* correction, say an exchange of a photon, or a gluon, to see the point.

Comment: Ahh... I see what you mean, thanks a lot!